# Access the weight matrix in Tensorflow in order to make apply changes to it in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I need a way to have access to the weight matrix in TensorFlow or Keras within each iteration, so that I can convert it into a format that I can use in Numpy to carry out certain operations on it, then send it back to TensorFlow.

For example, I want to change my filter such that some of the neurons are specified by others neuron of the filter. They have to be obtained as solutions of linear systems with other neurons as its coefficients, not by the learning process. As I could not find a way to do this in TensorFlow or Keras, I have to use Numpy.

I have found many questions with the same or similar titles, but none of them helped. I would appreciate any hints.

**EDIT**
let me explain the problem more clearly 
consider the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 5, 5, 1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1))

# create variable
weights = {
    "my_filter": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 1, 1]), name="my_filter"),
    "f_c": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25,1]), name="f_c") }


conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights["my_filter"], [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
flatten= tf.reshape(conv,[1,25])
logits= tf.matmul(flatten,weights["f_c"])


cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels= y))
optmize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
grads_and_vars = optmize.compute_gradients(cost)
#In this part before applying gradient I have to apply some complicated mathematical operation
train_op=optmize.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)



train_epochs=10
input_x = np.arange(25).reshape([1,5,5,1])
input_y = np.arange(1)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(train_epochs):

        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: input_x, y: input_y})
```

I have a 5*5 filter named my_filter and I want all its elements to be trained except for one of them, for exaple the (1,1) element, and I need the latter element to be determined by the rest of the elemnets. This has to be done in each iteration. This is exactly where my problem is. I know how to access the weight matrix after the training is finished, but I do not know how to do this within each iteration.

In my code, I have first computed the gradients, then made the changes,  and then applied the gradients. But the problem is that the gradients are tuples of types, for exapmle tensor, which are not easy to work with in Numpy. I need some method to convert these data to more familiar Numpy types.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras layers, and tf.keras.layers layers, support get_weights / set_weights methods, which return numpy arrays for the weights. So you can call get_weights, modify the result in numpy, and call set_weights back to put the new numpy values into tensorflow.

Something like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(...)
for batch in data:
  model.fit(batch)
  if ...:
    weights_as_numpy = model.get_weights()
    # modify the weights
    model.set_weights(weights_as_numpy)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question and added my code. I could not understand where I should use these methods within each iteration. As far as I know, they only give the weights after the training is finished.

Comment: Is possible for you to add some code to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you will need to be able to access to the weights. Instead of defining layer using tf.layers which automatically allocate variable, you can first get a variable yourself, and then call tf.nn instead.

```
# input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 5, 5, 1))
dummy_input = np.arange(25).reshape([1,5,5,1])

# create variable 
w = tf.get_variable('weight',[3,3,1,1])
# assign the variable to layer e.g. conv
y = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # read the weight
    random_weight  = sess.run(w, feed_dict={x:dummy_input})
    print('random weight', random_weight)

    # create some new values for weight
    new_weight = np.arange(9).reshape([3,3,1,1])
    # load it into the variable
    w.load(new_weight,sess)

    # read back and print to verify
    new_weight  = sess.run(w, feed_dict={x:dummy_input})
    print('new weight', new_weight)
```